# Como validar múltiplos campos em um formulário?

Tags: javascript, formulário

Estou precisando de uma ajuda com uma lógica básica...
Tenho um formulário com 4 campos que quando efetuo o `submit` no botão, preciso validar se pelo menos um dos campos da pesquisa foi preenchido. Só consegui validar oi primeiro campo, mas quando deixo o primeiro em branco e preencho o segundo, fala que nenhum campo foi preenchido...
Alguém poderia me ajudar?

```
function valida_form() {
    if ((document.getElementById("numeroPedido").value == null || document.getElementById("numeroPedido").value == "") && (document.getElementById("codigoCliente").value == null || document.getElementById("codigoCliente").value == "") && (document.getElementById("dataInicial").value == "" || document.getElementById("dataInicial").value == null) && (document.getElementById("dataFinal").value == "" || document.getElementById("dataFinal").value == null)) {
        alert('Informe um filtro de pesquisa.');
        return false
    } else {
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Coloca por favor o código que tens, senão vamos estar a adivinhar no escuro.

Comment: function valida_form(){
 if((document.getElementById("numeroPedido").value == null || document.getElementById("numeroPedido").value == "")
   && (document.getElementById("codigoCliente").value == null || document.getElementById("codigoCliente").value == "")
   && (document.getElementById("dataInicial").value == ""  || document.getElementById("dataInicial").value == null)
   && (document.getElementById("dataFinal").value == "" || document.getElementById("dataFinal").value == null)){
  alert('Informe um filtro de pesquisa.');
  return false
 } else {

  return true
 }
}

Comment: @Brunão vc poderia colocar o código html na pergunta para entendermos melhor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primeiro, vamos simplificar o seu código:

```javascript
function null_or_empty(str) {
    var v = document.getElementById(str).value;
    return v == null || v == "";
}

function valida_form() {
    if (null_or_empty("numeroPedido")
            && null_or_empty("codigoCliente")
            && null_or_empty("dataInicial")
            && null_or_empty("dataFinal"))
    {
        alert('Informe um filtro de pesquisa.');
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Ou seja se todos os campos forem vazios, ele pede para informar o filtro. Caso contrário (ou seja, se pelo menos um foi preenchido), aceita.

Talvez o que você queria é usar `||` ao invés de `&&`, de forma que daí o código só vai aceitar se todos eles forem preenchidos.

Pode ser que a sua lógica de validação devesse ser mais sofisticada:

```javascript
function valida_form() {
    var vazio1 = null_or_empty("numeroPedido");
    var vazio2 = null_or_empty("codigoCliente");
    var vazio3 = null_or_empty("dataInicial");
    var vazio4 = null_or_empty("dataFinal");

    if (vazio1 && vazio2 && vazio3 && vazio4) {
        alert('Informe um filtro de pesquisa.');
        return false;
    }
    if (!vazio1 && !valida_numero_pedido()) {
        alert('Informe um número de pedido válido.');
        return false;
    }
    if (!vazio2 && !valida_codigo_cliente()) {
        alert('Informe um código de cliente válido.');
        return false;
    }
    if (!vazio3 && !valida_data_inicial()) {
        alert('Informe uma data inicial válida.');
        return false;
    }
    if (!vazio4 && !valida_data_final()) {
        alert('Informe uma data final válida.');
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Além disso, vale a pena verificar se os campos não foram preenchidos apenas com espaços:

```javascript
function null_or_empty(str) {
    var v = document.getElementById(str).value;
    return v == null || v.trim() == "";
}
```

Comment: Valeu Victor!!!!! Muito obrigado..